# Using Thevenin's Equivalent Circuit in Solving Problems

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

Suppose that we have a circuit shown below. We can find the voltage of a particular component $A$ by finding the voltage across $R_2$.

If we find the voltage of the Thevenin equivalent circuit, the voltage across $R_2$ equals the $V_{oc}$ stated on the Thevenin equivalent diagram on the right.

Now, if we found the voltage of the component using the Thevenin equivalent circuit, we'd have to account for the fact $R_t$ has a voltage drop, so component $A$ will get a voltage of less than $V_{oc}$.

[image]

Imagine if $A$ was a capacitor. In the diagram on the left, its voltage at steady state would be $V_{oc}$, but on the right, it would less than $V_{oc}$ as there is a voltage drop on resistor $R_{t}$.

Why is there a difference? What am I think of that is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the steady state, there is no voltage drop across $R_t$. In the steady state, the capacitor is as charged as it's going to get, so there is no current through it. If there's no current through the capacitor, there's no current through $R_t$ either, so by Ohm's law there's no voltage across $R_t$, and the voltage across the capacitor is the full $V_{oc}$, just as in the diagram on the left.

Comment: That makes sense. However what if A was just a resistor? Then A has a voltage which is the same as $V_{oc}$ on the left, but on the right, it will have less as $R_t$ has a voltage drop too.

Comment: No, if $A$ is a resistor, then $A$ will have a voltage across it that's less than $V_{oc}$ on the left circuit, too. $A$ in parallel with $R_2$ is a smaller resistance than $R_2$, so the combination winds up with a smaller fraction of $V_s$ than what would be across $R_2$ if $A$ wasn't there.